# class method in Python unit test case

Tags: python

I am trying to mock up a function in the `setUpClass()` method, and then restore the function in the `tearDownClass()` method.

```
class MyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        cls.save_func = module.func
        module.func = lambda: True

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):

        module.func = cls.save_func
```

After the `tearDownClass()` method, I expected a call to `module.func()` would call the actual function. But it doesn't.

I did some debugging by printing the functions. I got the below outputs from the `tearDownClass()` method.

```
cls.save_func: <unbound method MyClass.save_func>
module.func:  <unbound method MyClass.save_func>
```

I was trying different things and I changed the methods from class methods to setup methods:

```
     def setUp(cls):

        cls.save_func = module.func
        module.func = lambda: True


    def tearDown(cls):

        module.func = cls.save_func
```

To my surprise, everything seems to be working. `module.func` is restored back, and when I print it, it gives me the function address.

```
module.func <function func at 0x89f9a74>
```

Can you please explain the behaviour?

Comment: Why aren't you using `unittest.patch` instead? (I know the question is nearly 10 years old, but it's something for readers now to consider.)

Answer (score 0):

Because `setUp` isn't a "static" `classmethod`, it requires an instance of the class.

Reference: [unittest basic example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example)

Comment: Wesley, can you please elaborate this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682504/how-to-write-a-stub-for-a-classmethod-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It's working differently without the @classmethod decorator because, in the revised code, "cls" is no longer the class:  it's the instance.  We normally designate the instance as "self", but "self" and "cls" aren't reserved words in Python--they're merely conventions. You can put anything you want in their places, though doing so will cause confusion (as is evident in the original code).

As for the I think the inconsistency between the outputs of the two versions of the code, I can't reproduce the behavior with the methods of an ordinary custom class, so it must have something to do with the unittest package.  However, I'm willing to bet it's due to the difference between class methods and instance methods.

Comment: The behavior described makes perfect sense in Python 2. In that version, if you store a normal function in a class variable and then access it via the class, you'll get an unbound method object. It works sort of like the normal function, but it does a type check when you call it to ensure the first argument (which it expects to be `self`) is an instance of the class it was fetched from (or an instance of a subclass). That's undesirable here, as `save_func` isn't intended as a method, but as data (that only happens to be a function). Fortunately Python 3 has done away with unbound methods.